# Flyway: How do i migrate to two different DBs using migrations in the same folder structure?

Tags: database, database-migration, database-schema, flyway

I'm new to flyway and I'm trying to figure out how to migration .sql changes to two different databases. Some of the migration files would apply to one database and some to another.  How do I differentiate between the two in the file in order to have them applied to the correct database?

Comment: sorry, perhaps I was unclear or maybe I misunderstand your reply. I think I get the common schema ... meaning that as I progress through DEV, TEST, Certification/UAT, to production. I migrating all of the DBs to a common schema.

This issue I have is that "dev" for me is really two different DBs , a source DB and a Target DB. I'm using this to automate the deployment of some ETL code. So some of the migration file would apply to one DB and some to the target. Is this possible to do?

Comment: That means you have a schema for each of these two separate databases and will have to individually migrate these two. But using the maven or ant plugin this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of flyway is that all databases are migrated to a *common* schema / state. See the article: [Why Database Migrations](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/whyDatabaseMigrations.html)

In flyway you have a 'global' list of version numbers (as defined by your list of migrations) and any database is either already on the desired (often highest) version or will be migrated to that version by applying all migrations inbetween.